# audio tag not working in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

I'm experimenting with the audio tag.

The file below does work in Google Chrome, but not in IE9. I'm always getting "audio tag not supported". I also tried wav, flac, wma --> same result.

I suspect there might some issue with the compaitibility mode, but I don't find where to change it.

Can anyone help? 
Kind regards
Georg

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio controls="controls" src="c:\concerto.mp3" >
       audio tag not supported.
    </audio>            
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the IE9 F12 Developer Tools, what Document Mode is the page listed as running in?  (Additionally, you shouldn't use a local file path that way; use file:///c:/concerto.mp3 instead)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the HTML5 doctype to the page and it should trigger standards mode in IE9.  You should also add a title element to [make the document valid](http://validator.nu/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add a title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio controls="controls" src="c:\concerto.mp3" >
       audio tag not supported.
    </audio>            
  </body>
</html>
```

If you're still having trouble, try adding this meta tag to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` makes the document HTML5

Comment: @Eonasdan Where? In the browser? No, browsers do not differentiate between "HTML4" and "HTML5" documents, just between various number of rendering modes (the standards and the quirks mode are the most important). If you'd add HTML 4.01 Strict doctype, `<audio>` would also work in IE9.

Comment: actually browsers *DO* differentiate between 4 and 5. That's why the doctype changed. See http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html

Comment: @Eonasdan the HTML5 doctype is the shortest string which triggers standards mode in all browsers, standards mode is triggered in just the same way by nearly any other doctype.  An HTML4 doctype will enable the `audio` element in IE9 just as much as the HTML5 doctype, but why bother with all the extra typing?

Comment: Thanks, the DOCTYPE was the solution !

Answer (score 0):

If 'audio' is working in chrome, safari, etc. but not in IE, check your meta tags.  I had one that referred to IE8 which stopped the 'audio' from functioning.  It was quite frustrating until I found the problem at which point the lights went on.

Answer (score 0):

IE plays files in your PC if you give full path as as a URL "file://c:/concert.mp3" or only file name "concert.mp3" if the file is in the same folder as the html file. Firefox also requires full path for files in other folders while Chrome seems to add 'file://' if it is not in the URL. This is a problem if you want to use the  to play local files if they are in other folders. The FileAPI does not allow you to find the path of the file.