# Audio TAG not working on IE9

Tags: jquery, html

I have jquery code that generates audio tag. The code generated works well in FF and Chrome but not in IE9. Below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var source = "/TTS.aspx?tts=" + $('.sound_hidden_field').text();
    $('body').append("<audio style='display:block' src='" + source + "' controls autoplay type='audio/wav'></audio>");
});
```

I have also tried

```
var s = "/TTS.aspx?tts=" + $('.sound_hidden_field').text();
var audioInterview = new Audio(s);
audioInterview.play();
```

But the code is just not working in IE. A black rectangle appears with cross at the center. Just like image tag when no image is to be found.

html generated is being passed by w3c validator.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358689/audio-tag-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Maybe this site will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Paul I have already tried your solution. Thanks

Comment: What audio formats are being provided?

Comment: @Mooseman only wav format is being provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 does *not* support HTML5 audio with a `.wav` format. `.mp3` only. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp for a table of compatibility.